# Text on image on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
        <a href="xxx.php" ><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['picture'] ?>" id="ppicture"></img></a>
```

I want it to have onhover a text on it like for example edit this picture.
I thought of backgroung image on css but this is not possible as I call the image from mysql and store the location in a $_SESSION as you can see. 
I'd appreciate any help.

EG. http://tympanus.net/crop1.1/ if you hover over the image, a pencil will appear. Instead of pencil, I want text to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using css positioning:

(1) create a div tag to function as a container for both the image and the text. Add a p tag around your text.

(2) add position:relative to the div you just created:

```
#div-name {
    position: relative;
}
```

(3) add a new style for the text that positions it relative to the div:

```
#div-name p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 168px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #AAA;
}
```

You should now have a caption on your picture. I leave the styling up to you, and you may want to consider using JQuery to make your edit tag appear on hover.

Comment: Ok yeah I made it using this and jquery thanx :D

Comment: @Simon just include the anchor tag inside of the p and you should be good. In fact you can really use almost anything here, even a div surrounding the anchor tag would work.

Comment: Hey maz yeah I figured out that later :) I don't know why but when I was donig that in the first place, it was messing the page.

Answer (score 1):

Place a `title="The text you want"` attribute on the `<img/>`.

```
<a href="xxx.php" ><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['picture'] ?>" id="ppicture" title="Your text" /></a>
```

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to have a stylized tooltip appear. If you'd prefer this route, I'd recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) plug-in.

Comment: I didn't mean the title thing. i wanted something more integrated like for example showing on the top of the image only the word edit and not over the mouse. Also title is not that fast and noticeable.

Comment: Then I recommend using jQuery and a tooltip plug-in. There are a great many and a Google search will help you find ones that might encompass the behavior you seek.

Comment: You were right can't be done without jQuery :) Thanx a lot :D
qTip looks awesome btw

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the title attribute?

```
<img ... title="Edit This Picture" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Using the title attribute of the img tag you can have hover text

```
<a href="xxx.php" ><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['picture'] ?>" id="ppicture" title="Edit this picture"></img></a>
```